# context.xml during deployment not found

Tags: spring, eclipse, tomcat, deployment

I have three Maven projects in eclipsew:

`webapp`, `serviceimpl` and `soa`.

`webapp` project contains `serviceimpl` and `soa` projects as maven dependencies (but as eclipse projects not as jars!)

In eclipse I can build the application successfully. When it comes to deploying the application on the `Tomcat server v7.0` in eclipse, I get the following error:

```
2017-12-19 09:58:35,591 INFO  info.magnolia.module.ModuleManagerImpl            : Starting module xyzwhatever
Dez 19, 2017 9:58:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2017-12-19 09:58:36,070 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader     : Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:META-INF/xyzwhatever-serviceimpl-context.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/xyzwhatever-serviceimpl-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/xyzwhatever-serviceimpl-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

But when I look for the generated `JAR` (that was generated during the Maven Build process) called `serviceimpl-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` it does contain `META-INF/xyzwhatever-serviceimpl-context.xml`. I have checked the `JAR` that has been generated in the local maven repository `.m2/...` and the one generated in the `generated` folder of the application. Both contain the `xml`file.

So why does the error during the deployment occur? Is there something wrong with the `classpath`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the solution is: in my various xml files I had to change:

`<import resource="classpath:xyzwhatever-serviceimpl-context.xml"/>`

to

`<import resource="classpath*:xyzwhatever-serviceimpl-context.xml"/>`

So the star (*) needs to be there!